# hash with array of hashes in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I know this topic has been covered but other posts usually has static hashes and arrays and the don't show how to load the hashes and arrays. 
I am trying to process a music library. I have a hash with album name and an array of hashes that contain track no, song title and artist. This is loaded from an XML file generated by iTunes.

```
the pared down code follows:

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use feature qw( say );
use XML::LibXML qw( );
use URI::Escape;

my $source = "Library.xml";
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

# load the xml doc

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $source )
    or warn $! ? "Error loading XML file: $source $!"
    : "Exit status $?";

    my %hCompilations;
    my %track;

    # extract xml fields
    my @album_nodes = $doc->findnodes('/plist/dict/dict/dict');
    for my $album_idx (0..$#album_nodes) {
        my $album_node = $album_nodes[$album_idx];
        my $trackName = $album_node->findvalue('key[text()="Name"]/following-sibling::*[position()=1]');
        my $artist = $album_node->findvalue('key[text()="Artist"]/following-sibling::*[position()=1]');
        my $album = $album_node->findvalue('key[text()="Album"]/following-sibling::*[position()=1]');
        my $compilation = $album_node->exists('key[text()="Compilation"]');

        # I only want compilations
        if( ! $compilation ) { next; }

        %track = (
                trackName => $trackName,
                trackArtist => $artist,
                );

        push @{$hCompilations{$album}} , %track;    
    }
#loop through each album access the album name field and get what should be the array of tracks
foreach my $albumName ( sort keys %hCompilations ) {
    print "$albumName\n";
    my @trackRecs = @{$hCompilations{$albumName}};

    # how do I loop through the trackrecs?
}
```

Comment: `foreach my $trackRec (@trackRecs)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn't doing what you think it is:

```
push @{$hCompilations{$album}} , %track;
```

This will unwrap your hash into a list of key/value pairs and will push each of those individually onto your array. What you want is to push a reference to your hash onto the array.

You could do that by creating a new copy of the hash:

```
push @{$hCompilations{$album}} , { %track };
```

But that takes an unnecessary copy of the hash - which will have an effect on your program's performance. A better idea is to move the declaration of that variable (`my %track`) inside the loop (so you get a new variable each time round the loop) and then just push a reference to the hash onto your array.

```
push @{$hCompilations{$album}} , \%track;
```

You already have the code to get the array of tracks, so iterating across that array is simple.

```
my @trackRecs = @{$hCompilations{$albumName}};

foreach my $track (@trackRecs) {
   print "$track->{trackName}/$track->{trackArtist}\n";
}
```

Note that you don't need the intermediate array:

```
foreach my $track (@{$hCompilations{$albumName}}) {
   print "$track->{trackName}/$track->{trackArtist}\n";
}
```

Comment: much thanks. I need to dig into the basics. I get so confused when it comes to simple structures. thanks again.

Comment: @Coltrane58: I recommend the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). That's how I got to grips with this stuff many years ago.

Answer (score 2):

first of all you want to push the hash as a single element, so instead of

```
    push @{$hCompilations{$album}} , %track;
```

use

```
    push @{$hCompilations{$album}} , {%track};
```

in the loop you can access the tracks with:

```
foreach my $albumName ( sort keys %hCompilations ) {
    print "$albumName\n";
    my @trackRecs = @{$hCompilations{$albumName}};

    # how do I loop through the trackrecs?
    foreach my $track (@trackRecs) {
       print $track->{trackName} . "/" . $track->{trackArtist} . "\n";
    }
}
```